# Copy/Paste text in Commit Changes Dialog - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, copy-paste

Can I copy, paste and delete text in Android Studio's '**Commit Changes**' dialog box?

Only backspacing works in my case.

[image]

---

Android Studio 1.3.2 on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: When did this start happening? Have you installed a new plugin in recent times or was this always a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a similar problem with another Jetbrains product (Intellij IDEA) on Linux (Arch Linux to be specific). In my case, the fix was to disable two plugins that I had installed earlier: Idea VIM and .gitignore plugin (am not entirely sure which of these two was the real culprit but did not bother investigating any further since I did not need either of them).

If you have either of those plugins installed, can you try disabling them? I would recommend starting just by disabling Idea VIM plugin.

---

#### (drastic) Suggestion - Reset config

***Only do this if nothing else works and remember to backup your config first!***

If you do not have the offending plugins, does temporarily resetting the configuration work for you? Test this by doing the following:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Rename `/home/yourname/.AndroidStudio1.3/config`
3. Restart Android Studio

It might be a bit painful to redo some of the necessary configuration (for instance, repo configuration to be able to make commits etc) but if it works, you know that it is something in your configuration.